# Computing square roots and calculus

Tags: calculus, logic, model-theory, formal-systems

If one were to verify that

$$ \sqrt{2} < 3 $$

would the underlying formalisation require a logic more expressive than first-order? Or, is FOL sufficient since real numbers can be formalised in set theory?

How about evaluating differentials, like

$$ \frac{d}{dy} (3x+2) $$

what how expressive does the logic need to be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Comparing particular algebraic numbers (localized away from their Galois conjugates by inequalities, such as the *positive* root of $X^2=2$) can be done in any theory that supports arithmetic calculation.  For example, the first-order theory of real-closed fields is decidable and that includes decisions about statements of the form $a > b$ comparing two real algebraic numbers.

Model theory of differential (and difference) fields and rings usually takes place in a first-order logic context similar to fields.  Theorems are proved by second-order methods but the object of study is a first-order theory.

Comment: I see. Why are theorems proved by second-order methods? Can you name some example objects of study that are second or higher order theories?